# Reading /proc/pid/smaps

Tags: bash, file, proc

I'm trying to get the value of the lines with the same name in a smap file using bash, but i don't know how to do it.
For example I need to get the value of every line starting with "Size:" int order to get the total size. 
What is the best way to do it?

Example of smap file:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images. Post text

Answer (score 1):

I assume size is only gave in kB

```
#!/usr/env/bin bash
sum=0
grep "^Size:" /proc/pid/smaps | (while read line
do
 size=$(echo "$line" | tr -s '\t' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
 sum=$((sum + size))
done
echo $sum) | xargs -I{} echo "total size: {} kB"
```

---

1- Get all size lines

```
grep "^Size:" /proc/pid/smaps
```

2- Retrieve the interesting part of the current matching line and perfom stuff on it (in our case sum it)

```
while read line
do
 size=$(echo "$line" | tr -s '\t' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
 sum=$((sum + size))
done
```

Then enclose it into parenthesis whith an `echo` to pull out value of the `while` statement

```
| (while read line
do
 size=$(echo "$line" | tr -s '\t' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
 sum=$((sum + size))
done
echo $sum) |
```

3- Now the total size is available from the pipe and you can use it

```
 xargs -I{} echo "total size: {} kB"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
SUM=0
while read -r line
do
    f=($line)
    if [ "${f[0]}" == "Size:" ]
    then
        size=$(numfmt --from=iec --suffix=B "${f[1]}${f[2]^^}")
        SUM=$(($SUM + ${size: : -1}))
    fi
done < /proc/$$/smaps
echo "I have $(numfmt --to=iec $SUM) in /proc/$$/smaps!"
```

The above script loops `/proc/$$/smaps` spliting each line by whitespace then uses [numfmt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) to convert any value of `Size` to bytes.